# How to show button dynamically on a Jquery Table

Tags: jquery

In a table , User can delete rows by clicking on the Remove Button 
User cannot delete all the rows , One row must be at least Present

So for this i am checking the table length

```
if($("#dynamicTable1 tr").length==2) 
  {

        $("#dynamicTable1 tr").find('td:last-child').hide();
  }
```

When a new row has been added to the table dynamically , how to add /
show the Remove button Which got hidden Previously

https://jsfiddle.net/qvtL6qf2/355/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  jQuery("#addrow").click(function() {
    id++;
    var row = jQuery('.samplerow tr').clone(true);
    row.find("input:text").val("");
    row.attr('id', id);
    row.appendTo('#dynamicTable1');
    return false;
  });

  $('.remove').on("click", function() {

    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    if ($("#dynamicTable1 tr").length == 2) {

      $("#dynamicTable1 tr").find('td:last-child').remove();
    }



  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dynamicTable1">
  <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Place</th>
    <th>Skill</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld4" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld5" /></td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld4" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld5" /></td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add New Row" />

<table class="samplerow" style="display:none">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld4" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld5" /></td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Repeat your logic and optionally call `show()` ?

Comment: Or actually you don't even need to perform the conditional.  If your users add a new row, show the delete buttons.

Comment: Side note, you are repeating ids in your markup which is invalid by web standards.

Comment: thanks for this  users add a new row, show the delete buttons

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing the delete buttons, hide them.  And then when you add a new row, show them again.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var id = 0;
  var $dynamicTable = $('#dynamicTable1');
  
  $("#addrow").on('click', function() {
    id++;
    var row = $('.samplerow tr').clone(true);
    row.find("input:text").val("");
    row.attr('id', id);
    $dynamicTable.append(row);
    $dynamicTable.find('tr td:last-child').show();
    return false;
  });

  $dynamicTable.on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    
    if ($dynamicTable.find('tr').length < 3) {
      $dynamicTable.find('tr td:last-child').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dynamicTable1">
  <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Place</th>
    <th>Skill</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld4" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld5" /></td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld4" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld5" /></td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add New Row" />

<table class="samplerow" style="display:none">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld4" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fld5" /></td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```